# It has come out,come undone?& Pull out

Tags: word-usage, spoken-english

### Question1

If we tuck in a bedspread or covers on the corners of the bed and after a while they're sticking out again, what will be a natural way to express it:

> The bedspread has **come undone.**
>
> The bedspread has **come out** on a corner.
>
> The bedspread has **come untucked.**

And what about a shirt that had been tucked but now has come undone/untucked?

> The shirt has **come out.**
>
> The shirt has **come untucked.**
>
> The shirt has **come undone.**

In the above 6 sentences what will be used :**come out/undone/untucked**?

---

### Another question(2)

If someone asks someone to untuck his/her shirt, will it be natural to say:

> **Pull out** your shirt.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92840/discussion-on-question-by-its-about-english-it-has-come-out-come-undone-pull).

Answer (score 1):

Probably "has come undone" or "has come untucked" would work. I'm thinking perhaps that if there's a need to understand that it's at the corner for some reason you could be explicit about that for clarity: "The bedspread came undone at the corner." Since shirts don't have corners, it would just be the shirt or the shirt-tails.

And as for asking one to untuck their shirt, I've almost always heard it as "untuck your shirt". I think if someone said, "Pull out your shirt," it would sound a bit odd to me since it's not usage I'm accustomed to, but I'd likely understand what was meant. Undo your shirt, however, has, to me, a totally different meaning.

Comment: Is the use of "come out" unnatural in the case of "bedspread" and "shirt"?

Comment: So is the use of "come out" natural????

Answer (score -1):

It is better to use simpler tenses in English to aid in clarity.  Then from there pick the simpler sentence that has all the meaning.

The options you gave are in the **Perfect Tense** English usage would pick the **Past Tense** instead.

> The bedspread has come undone.  --> The bedspread **came** undone
>
> The bedspread has come out on a corner. --> The bedspread **came** *out of a* corner.
>
> The bedspread has come untucked. --> The bedspread **is untucked.**

Comment: And what about a "shirt"? "Your shirt has come out". Does this sound natural?

Comment: So is the use of "come out" natural?

Comment: @Vincenzo I have down-voted your answer. It does not address the question and it offers opinions without justification. The choice of tense depends on context and has little bearing on clarity.